# How to apply 'OR' between multiple 'AND' operators. Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I want to built this search:

(A AND B AND C) OR (C AND D AND E)

I'm trying with this code.

```
.search(['&', '&',  (A), (B),(C) , '|', '&','&', (C), (D), (E)])
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AND`, `OR` functions defined inside [expression](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/osv/expression.py#L272) file

***Example***:

```
OR([AND([A, B, C]), AND([C, D, E])])
```

Answer (score 0):

The software seems to use [prefix ("polish") notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), so the operator appears before its operands, hence `A AND B` being written `AND A B`.

The same then would apply to `OR`, you'd write `A OR B` as `OR A B`. Therefore

```
(A AND B AND C) OR (C AND D AND E)
```

would be transcribed to (formatted for clarity)

```
OR
    AND
        AND
            A
            B
            C
    AND
        AND
            C
            D
            E
```

therefore

```
|, &, &, A, B, C, &, &, C, D, E
```

When using polish notation, it can help to transcribe to and from [lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) as S-Expressions are basically polish notation with disambiguating brackets (which also allows variable arity). This both makes things clearer (the brackets help a lot and there are lots of editors with lisp support), and it allows evaluating the expressions in a lisp shell which would probably be convenient to get the logic right.

e.g.

```
(or
    (and (and A B) C)
    (and (and C D) E))
```

Note: in all the lisps I know `and` is n-ary so this is equivalent to

```
(or
    (and A B C)
    (and C D E))
```

however I'd suggest sticking to the binary form as it makes transcribing back and forth much easier.