# Set Complex domain on many2one field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, field, many-to-one

Hi I want to set domain on my many2one field in odoo 13 but I can't set complex operators... actually I don't know how set where conditions that exist at my postgersql as domain on my many2one field this is my condition in my postgres :

```
(code in ( 19 ,34  ) or (type = 118) or ((total_value > 0) and (type not in (66 , 96)))) and ( code not in (66,67))
```

I tried this one :

```
"['|','|','&','&'('code', 'in', ( 19 ,34 )),('type', '=', 118),('total_value ', '>', 0),('type', 'not in', (66 , 96)),('code ', 'not in', (66 , 67))]"
```

but it's not my condition. simply I want **A OR B OR (C AND D) AND E**  but this domain give me **A OR B OR C AND D AND E**
which is wrong semantically and logically. can someone help me??? I'm really confused :(

Comment: You can use the `OR` and `AND` functions. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286179/how-to-apply-or-between-multiple-and-operators-odoo-14/72286463#72286463)